# JQuery Slider Value from next Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, slider

I have a set of JQuery sliders and corresponding value textboxes on my page.

All is working fine and the sliders and textboxes are updating each other on a change. My only remaining issue is setting the initial values on the page load.

Using the class of the corresponding object works (yellow highlight), but in my other example (blue highlight) I need to use the next() function as these elements are in a repeater.

What is the best way to set the initial slider value in the blue examples on the page load?

Thanks

[Example Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjKja.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The each() function seems to do the trick here:

`$(".compDiscSlider").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).next("input").val();
        $(this).slider({
            range: "min",
            animate: true,
            step: 0.25,
            min: 0.00,
            max: 100.00,
            value: val,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).next("input").val(ui.value);
            }
        })
    });`